# InvalidOperationException: The target must be a boolean

Tags: c#, wpf, opacity, ivalueconverter

I have `UserControl`. In it I have `Grid`. To this `Grid` I set `Opacity` which is `0` or `1` according to value of another control. To set it I am using next converter :

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(bool), typeof(double))]
public class OpacityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var b = value as bool?;
        if (targetType != typeof(bool) && !b.HasValue)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The target must be a boolean");
        if (b.HasValue)
        {
            return b.Value ? 1 : 0;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Converter which transform bool value into `Opacity`. For me it all seems correct.

But when I go to designer of page where I use that `UserControl` I see error

> InvalidOperationException: The target must be a boolean
>   at SizeStream.WPF.Converters.OpacityConverter.Convert(Object value, Type targetType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)

When I build my project everything is Ok. But In designer - not.

Restarting VS 2013 doesn't help.

Why there are such problem? Thanks

---

```
<controls:MultiSelectComboBox Tag="{Binding PanelLoading, Converter={StaticResource InverseConverter}}" SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedBrandsList, Mode=TwoWay}"  Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="BrandsFilter" DefaultText="Brand" ItemsSource="{Binding BrandsList}" Style="{StaticResource FiltersDropDowns}"/>
```

From this element I get `Tag` value.

```
<Grid Background="#FF826C83" Name="DropDown" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}" Opacity="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}, Converter={StaticResource OpacityConverter}}">
```

Here I use converter

---

Answer :

With help of StackOverflow users my final code looks like :

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (targetType != typeof(double))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The target must be a double");
        if (value is bool)
        {
            return (bool)value ? 1 : 0;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: can post your Xaml ?

Comment: @SamTheDev, added xaml

Comment: Why are you using a nullable boolean?

Comment: @ChrisF, cause when I try to convert `value` to `bool` I get error `The as operator must be used with a reference type or nullable type ('bool' is a non-nullable value type)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (targetType != typeof(bool) && !b.HasValue)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("The target must be a boolean");
```

If you intend to convert from bool to double, then your target type must be checked against "double" in the above code.

Comment: OMG! Really! What a stupid mistake. Thanks. I've was thinking about `sourceType`